# Pascal-like Triangle Relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, recurrence-relations, recreational-mathematics

I was fiddling around with an expansion, trying to find the coefficients of a certain formula, and I found that they satisfied the following relation for $0 \leq c \leq r$

$$
 N(r,c) = \left\{ \begin{array}{lr} 1 & \text{if} \ c=r \\ 2^r & \text{if} \ c=0 \\ 2N(r-1, c) + N(r-1, c-1) & \text{if} \ 0 < c < r  \end{array} \right.
$$

Then I noticed that if we interpret $r$ and $c$ as row and column it makes a pascal-like triangle of the following form:

[image]

and I was wondering if there exists a general way to find explicit formulae for each term of triangles such at this one?

That is to say, if we define the formula

$$
 N_{a,b}(r,c) = \left\{ \begin{array}{lr} 1 & \text{if} \ c=r=0 \\ b^r & \text{if} \ c=r \\ a^r & \text{if} \ c=0 \\  aN(r-1, c) + bN(r-1, c-1) & \text{if} \ 0 < c < r  \end{array} \right.
$$

is there a way to find $N_{a,b}(r,c)$ explicitly?

---

Edit: By observation I noticed that $N(r,c) = N_{2,1}(r,c) = 2^{r-c}{r \choose c}$, but I would still like to leave this post open to see if there is a general way to tackle this problem, and also to tackle $N_{a,b}$ more generally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out my own solution to this problem, but its a one of those cases where the solution seems to come from nowhere.

To do so, suppose we have two variables $X,Y$ such that

$$
 XY = aY + bYX
$$

then suppose there exists constants $N_{a,b}(r,c)$ such that

$$
 X^{r}Y = \sum_{c=0}^{r} N_{a,b}(r,c) YX^{c},
$$

then

$$
 X^{r+1}Y = \sum_{c=0}^{r}N_{a,b}(r,c) (XY)(X^{c}) = \sum_{c=0}^{r}N_{a,b}(r,c) (aY + bYX)(X^{c}) = \sum_{c=0}^{r}aN_{a,b}(r,c)YX^{c} + \sum_{c=0}^{r}bN_{a,b}(r,c)YX^{c+1}
$$

but this sum equals

$$
\sum_{c=0}^{r}aN_{a,b}(r,c)YX^{c} + \sum_{c=1}^{r+1}bN_{a,b}(r,c-1)YX^{c}
$$

which in turn equals

$$
 \left\{ \sum_{c=1}^{r}\left(aN_{a,b}(r,c) + bN_{a,b}(r,c-1)\right)YX^{c} \right\} + aN_{a,b}(r,0)Y + bN_{a,b}(r,r)YX^{r+1}
$$

and so by comparing coefficients of $YX^{c}$ as $c$ varies we see that these constants $N_{a,b}(r,c)$ must satisfy (if they exist)

\begin{align*}
 N_{a,b}(r+1,c) = \left\{ \begin{array}{lr} 1 & \text{if} \ c=r=0 \\ aN_{a,b}(r,0) & \text{if} \ c=0 \\ bN_{a,b}(r,r) & \text{if} \ c=r \\  aN(r, c) + bN(r, c-1) & \text{if} \ 0 < c < r + 1  \end{array} \right.
\end{align*}

and so we see that these constants $N_{a,b}(r,c)$ (if they exists satisfy exactly the relations in the Pascal-like triangle).

But we can also prove (by easy induction) that

$$
 X^rY = Y(a + bX)^{r}
$$

and so by the binomial theorem

$$
 X^rY = \sum_{c=0}^{r} {r \choose c} a^{r-c}b^{c}YX^{c} 
$$

which proves that firstly these constants $N_{a,b}(r,c)$ exist, and further that

$$
 N_{a,b}(r,c) = {r \choose c} a^{r-c}b^{c}
$$